# Error when running new flutter installation

Tags: flutter

I'm using Flutter from stable channel, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Linux), Android SDK version 29.0.2 and Android Studio version 3.5. on ubuntu 18.4. All necessary PATHs are set.

The doctor summary shows no problems.

When I run "flutter build" I get the error:

```
Initializing gradle...                                             
Resolving dependencies...                                               
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/.../flutter/raw/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to
/.../android-sdk/ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.627 secs

Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:558)
    ...
    ...
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/.../flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Command: /... /flutter/raw/android/gradlew app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

How can the problem be fixed?

Comment: Would you share your build.gradle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that NDK is not on your PATH or the project is looking in the wrong place. 
First verify you have NDK installed/.

[Install NDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk)

Tick this box. [image]

If NDK is indeed installed you will need to change project structure to point to the correct location. [image: Project Structure]

Comment: I've android-studio and android-sdk installed. Is NDK a different thing? Is it necessary to have three of them in addition to flutter?

Comment: It may have been unchecked by accident? Unclear as to why you do not have it on disk. Easy to fix though.  In the SDK Tools tab tick of NDK

Comment: @Michael Yes the NDK is the Nougat Development Kit.

Answer (score 2):

Per https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53657#issuecomment-795808016, the recommended solution is now to simply upgrade your gradle version to 4.1.2 or higher.

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'`